# Google Script Editor OnChange Trigger not Working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am running a script in google sheets script editor, to trigger the script I use the installable trigger `onChange()`. I followed the steps available on in the documentations.
But nothing happen when I do something on my worksheet.

Here is my code

```
function createSpreadsheetChangeTrigger() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   ScriptApp.newTrigger('onChange')
     .forSpreadsheet(ss)
     .onChange()
     .create();
   }  

function onChange(){
 Logger.log("onChange event fired");
}
```

I don't understand what is going wrong.
Can anyone help me please?

Thanks

Comment: Editing by adding or deleting content. Or formatting.
Even adding a row didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have will work, but you have to actually "install" the trigger first. To do that go to **Edit --> Current Project's Triggers.** Click on the link **No triggers set up. Click here to add one now** and make the selections below:

[image]

Now check your Logger after making a change to your spreadsheet and you get:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

> But nothing happens when I do something on my worksheet.

You have to add a row, add a column, delete a row or delete a column to trigger `onChange()`.

I think you need [`onEdit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onEdit()) trigger. It fires when the range is edited.

> I'm looking for an event that will be fired when the user is selecting
>   something on the spreadsheet

This is currently not possible that's all we have:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

The reason developers did not include such a trigger:

- Sheets are launched online and let multiple users. I think the `onSelect` trigger would crash the server.

Comment: For the project I'm working on, I already tried the onEdit trigger.
But it won't fit.
I'm looking for an event that will be fired when the user is selecting something on the spreadsheet, and I hoped that the onChange trigger was the one.

Comment: Hi @ysibilly, this is not possible.

Comment: thanks for your answer .
I think I'll have to find an other way to do get my selection.